# Using SharePoint workflow to copy column content to another list

Tags: workflow-activity

When creating a workflow to copy content from one list to another, do the columns have to be in the same format?

**Background:** I have already created a workflow to copy column information from one list to another, once the origination list entry is approved. Everything works fine, with the exception of one column. The columns in the originating list and destination list are the same, except for one exception. I have one column in the originating list using a lookup (from another list), and that same column needs to be set in a Text format, in the Destination list. I need this destination list column in a text format so it will be available as a lookup in an infopath form, for a 3rd list (where observation data will be collected).

When this one particular column was in the same format between the list (meaning the lookup in one list was also set up with the same look up in the other list) this column's content copied over with no issue. When both list were set up this way, this column's content would not show up as a lookup in the 3rd list used for data collection and needing this columns input as a selection.

In the current configuration, I have no problem manually copy and pasting the missing column data from the origination list to the destination list, even though the columns are not in same format (Lookup in origination list and text in destination list). Not sure why I cannot get the workflow to do that for me.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online or a particular on-prem version?  Which workflow technology are you using?

Comment: I am using an on-premise version. Currently using SharePoint farm 2019, but Infopath is 2013 and using 2010 workflow functionality.

Comment: Also using SharePoint Designer 2013.

Answer (score 0):

In the User Interface, the Lookup column will display the text value from the source list, which means you can copy and paste manually through the UI.

But behind the surface, SharePoint stores this in a FieldLookupValue.  Depending on what workflow technology you are using, you can coerce it into text, but then you will end up with the source item's ID and text value concatenated together, something like "42#, TextHere".

Both SharePoint Designer workflows and Power Automate Flows have the ability to grab the text of the source lookup value, but you won't be able to just do a loop where `list1item["Column1"] = list2item["Column2"]`, you will have to make a special case for that field.  If you add more details about your version and workflow platform, I can give you some tips how to get the value you want copied over.

Comment: The list are operating in 2019 SharePoint farm (previously upgraded from 2013 and 2010). Using SharePoint Designer 2013, but 2010 SharePoint Workflow technology. Company did not update SharePoint Worklow from 2010 technology, when updating the SharePoint farm from 2010 to 2013 and then 2019. The InfoPath Designer is 2013.

Comment: So are you using the built-in 2010 workflow action "Copy List Item"?

Comment: I am using Copy Item. In the workflow step, if the current item:Approval Status equals Approved, Copy item in Current Item to the selected list

Comment: So, this is kind of a pain, but the next step after "Copy Item", you will need to add an Update Item to update the new item that was just created by the Copy action, explicitly set the Lookup field, and in the get value from current item, when you choose the Lookup field, you get the option to choose LookupID or LookupValue, make sure you choose LookupID.

Comment: OK. So should this be another step independent of the Copy item or is it OK to put following the Copy Item as the next action. In this workflow, I only have the one step, but it contains several actions.

Comment: I am curious if it would be OK to add in the line immediately following the Copy Item. I am adding the step immediately after as follows. Update Item in this list. When I select this list, I get a Update List Item box which indicates current item. Do I change that to the list to be updated or do I keep it as Current Item.

Comment: So what I had tried or interpreted from your response did not work. I likely applied it incorrectly.So I am creating a Step 2 and adding an action for Update item in this list. When I click on this list, I get the box to Update List Item. Do I keep the List (field) set to Current item or do I change that? If keeping as current item, I am assuming I have to select Add to define the Value Assignment. i get the option for Set this field: and To this value:. The set this field would be the field I need to update and the To this value would be Lookup ID. Is this correct?

Comment: I tried the above and it did not work either. I am sure I am not doing something correctly.

Comment: No, you don't want to update current item, you want to update the destination item that you just created by the Copy action.  This action should come immediately after the copy, and can be in the same step.

Comment: That makes sense. I wish there was a way to screen share to make sure I do this right. Do you know if there is a way to post images?

Comment: Not on a comment, but you can post images in your Question:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317576/editor-improvements-for-images-and-links

Comment: Are you OK if I move this to Chat?

Comment: lol, yeah, the discussion is long enough it is probably nagging you to.  I don't know if I will be able to be immediately responsive most of that day, but will try.

Comment: Here is where I am at. 1). Added Update List Item. 2). Selected this list to get Update List Item box. 3). Selected the target List (instead of Current Item). Do I click Add to set the Field and Value or at the bottom of the box is an area to Find the List Item (where you choose a field from the selected list and matching value)?

Comment: Yes you want to "find" the List Item that you just created via the Copy action.  I don't enough about your metadata, but you'll have to look for it via some field that should be unique.